# Django: Filling out a ManytoMany relationship for every new form in a formset

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm using these 3 models (simplified):

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Model2(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Model3(models.Model):
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
    model2 = models.ForeingKey(Model2)
```

I have a form for Model1 and a formset for Model2s that work but the problem is that for every Model2 in the formset I want there to also be a Model3 that connects Model2 to Model1.

How do I add Model3 so it gets filled out for each Model2 in the formset?
I tried finding a solution using inlineformsets or modelformsets but I still don't really understand them. I don't even know if that's the right direction to go in.

I'm looking for anything that will point me in the right direction.

Comment: Since Model3 only connects Model2 to Model1, it seems that you don't need any user data in it. Is that the case? In that case then you may be able to achieve this in the form's save logic. It depends whether all the Model2 instances in the submitted formset need linking to the Model1 instance submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming my question above is along the right lines, then in the POST-handling part of your view:

```
if model_one_form.is_valid() and model_two_formset.is_valid():
    obj_one = model_one_form.save()
    for model_two_form in model_two_formset:
        obj_two = model_two_form.save()
        obj_three = Model3.objects.create(model1=obj_one, model2=obj_two)
```

It seems that something this simple could be done better using a straightforward ManyToManyField, or if you need access to Model3, then the same but using the `through` argument. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through Of course, your case may be more complicated than you've indicated in your question.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I'm still learning Django and didn't even realize there was a create function for models. Thank you! As for ManyToMany Fields I wanted to learn what Django's inbuilt stuff was doing behind the scenes so I've been doing it myself for now. I'll probably use the the inbuilt stuff once it feels less like magic and more like a simpler way of doing ManytoMany fields.

Comment: That's a sensible approach. You can think of `obj_one = Model1.objects.create(foo=bar)` as a shortcut for `obj_one = Model1(foo=bar); obj_one.save()`.